# Input focus Jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, textarea, onblur

I am trying to fix this piece of code which on Click, removed the input's value, and on Blur returns the value back into the input. You can see my jsFiddle here to see what I mean:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ys7c/)

**The problem**

It seems to work for the first two inputs, but then the rest don't seem to do anything. It also appears to not work with the textarea. Strange behavior here but I'm sure a Javascript head can sort this one out.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now it works: :-) http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/3Ys7c/3/

Use the jQuery [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) attrbute:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input, textarea").focus(function() {
        if (!$(this).data('original')) {
            $(this).data('original', $(this).val());
        }
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('original')) {
            $(this).val('').css({
                'color': "#999999",
                'background-color': '#c6e9ff'
            });
        }
    });
    $("input, textarea").blur(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val($(this).data('original')).css({
                'background-color': '#ffffff'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The reason why yours did not work is because you were using `this.id` which none of them had. If you just use the `data` attribute of each input, then each input knows what it should and should not be :-)

Comment: @remi90 also -- dont use `attr('value')` that is what `.val()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply give your elements an `id=""` property.